# Visual Studio 2010 not running the first of two projects

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna

So I have two projects in VS 2010, the first is a windows form app that handles the configuration of a game (the two projects together make up a game).

The second project (that is a dependency of the first / the first has a reference to it) is an XNA game. Since I integrated the two, everything has been fine, I press the play button, the first form in the first project opens, I can configure it through another form, then that form runs the game.

Now what happens is when I press play VS skips over the first project entirely, and starts the game. This is really really weird, it started happening just after I restarted my computer and I can't figure out why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the startup project has been changed from your Windows Form to your XNA game. They are both part of the same solution, yes?

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y(v=vs.100).aspx).

Make sure the startup project in your solution is the Windows Form and not the XNA game.

Comment: Ah yes thank-you very much, I see now that the start-up project's name in the solution explorer is in bold. I right clicked on the first one and then on `Set as StartUp project`  I'm not sure how it got changed but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your files from temp is deleted.

Can you post screen shot so that we can figure out what's wrong in VS ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, a screen shot of what?